# iOS UIPasterboard does not show message on device

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

I want to show user message, that something was copied to UIPasterboard.

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "\(contact.numFirst)"
```

In simulator it shows some general popup, but on device not.
Can I do it without external libraries?